# How to implement Rate Limiter in rest api call, spring mvc application without using springboot, or cloud?

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, rate-limiting

i have a application which runs on a tomcat using  spring and java. we are not using spring boot, cloud. as per requirement, if any brute force attack happened, need to use rate limiter concept in rest api calls. is there any example?. i couldn't find anywhere. mostly in google am seeing that all examples related spring boot only. please share any implementation link if anybody has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some standalone rate limiter libraries that you can consider to use. Some of the well-known one are from [resilience4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/ratelimiter) and [Guava](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-rate-limiter). But please note that they are not distributed , meaning that the rate limiting will only be applied to a single instance and will not be shared across all the app instances.

Another thing normally you need to think about is if the rate limiter is applied per IP or per user or both. Codewise , it basically means that you have to maintain a map of the rate limiter instance per IP/user/both and get the rate limiter belongs to that IP/user/both to check if the rate limiter hits the limit before processing an API request in the spring-mvc controller method.

Comment: Thank you. but if we use ip, how to maintain in map as its dyanamic IP instance?

Comment: yse. to keep it simple, you can use a local cache . the key is the IP and the values is that ip 's rate limiter. Think that you also need to  configure the the cache will automatically expiry if an entry is not accessed for more than certain time period in order to prevent OOM

Comment: Okay. thank you  Ken Chan . Do we have any aws api service for throttling rest call instead of doing the implementation in Spring?

Comment: if you are using AWS gateway , it already has the IP rate limiting feature (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html)